# Get id from Values in a StringList

Tags: delphi

I have a StringList with 2 rows

```
aOldPriceTerms[0] = 'FuelAddition=336643160'
aOldPriceTerms[1] = 'Freight=336643155'
```

So it works fine to use

aOldPriceTerms.Values['Freight'] -> '336643155'

I want to have a list of ID's from the list.

So simply

```
'FuelAddition','Freight'
```

Currently I use this code where aOldPriceTerms is the actual StringList.

```
function GetList(aOldPriceTerms: TStringList): String;
var
  vOldTerm : string;
  vOldTermsList : TStringList;
begin
  vOldTermsList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := aOldPriceTerms.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      vOldTerm := Copy(aOldPriceTerms[i], 1, (Pos('=', aOldPriceTerms[i])-1));
      vOldTermsList.Add(vOldTerm);
    end;

    Result := vOldTermsList.CommaText;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vOldTermsList);
  end;
end;
```

My question is there a cleaner way to get the ids ?

Answer (score 7):

Example is from the [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=tstringlist), but `TStringList.Names` is also described in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Names)

```
  // Now display all name and age pair values
  for i := 0 to names.Count-1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(names.Names[i]+' is '+names.ValueFromIndex[i]);
  end;
```

Comment: Names is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to link to the documentation rather than delphibasics. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Names

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TALNVStringList` (NV for nameValue) from alcinoe (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) to handle Name and Value without all the time splitting the string

`TALNVStringList` is exactly the same as `TStringList` (nothing to change in the code except replacing `TstringList` by `TALNVStringList`)  except that it's more efficient in speed because it's store the name in one dedicated field and the value in another dedicated field (no need to do all the time `pos('=')` and `copy()` to retrieve the name and the value of the row)

```
  for i := 0 to aOldPriceTerms.Count-1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(aOldPriceTerms.Names[i]+' is '+aOldPriceTerms.ValueFromIndex[i]);
  end;
```

Exe demo showing the speed penalty of classic TstringList: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALSortedListBenchmark/win32/ALSortedListBenchmark.exe

Answer (score -2):

To get all the id's

```
for name in names.Names do
begin
  i := names.IndexOf[name];
end;
```

or

To get all the Values

```
for name in vOldTermsList.Names do
begin
   Value := vOldTermsList.Value[name];
end;
```

Comment: This is expensive because you have to perform lookups inside your loop body. Better is to access by index, as per the [answer from Jacek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481369/505088).